# How to implement "Login using google" in my website?

Tags: jakarta-ee, web-applications, oauth, oauth-2.0, scribe

I want to  implement "Login using Google" type login in my J2EE Web Application based on JSP and Servlets. How to implement it.

Let I explain ::

> 1) The user clicks "Login using google" . 
>   2) Now he redirected to Google's page and clicks that "Allow Access". 
>   3) after clicking Allow Access , he redirected to his User Portal

This is the procedure . I used Scribe APi but I don't know how implement it in a jsp page.

Can you explain me how to  implement this using any open source API's ?

> ( I searched StackOVerflow but i only found for php/asp but no for jsp)

## please don't close my question since I am new to stackoverflow.

Comment: How about searching google devel doc: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login

Answer (score 0):

Sample Java Code

```
// Create a state token to prevent request forgery.
  // Store it in the session for later validation.
  String state = new BigInteger(130, new SecureRandom()).toString(32);
  request.session().attribute("state", state);
  // Read index.html into memory, and set the Client ID,
  // Token State, and Application Name in the HTML before serving it.
  return new Scanner(new File("index.html"), "UTF-8")
      .useDelimiter("\\A").next()
      .replaceAll("[{]{2}\\s*CLIENT_ID\\s*[}]{2}", CLIENT_ID)
      .replaceAll("[{]{2}\\s*STATE\\s*[}]{2}", state)
      .replaceAll("[{]{2}\\s*APPLICATION_NAME\\s*[}]{2}",
                  APPLICATION_NAME);
```

It's available in Java, as far as the flow is concerned, for the sake of completeness of this answer, I would like to give a brief overview.

1. User clicks on "Sign in with Google"
2. Due to the use of javascript, user is redirected to some google-page where the user is 
   asked for permission.
3. On accepting or granting permission, the Google redirects the user (sends the response accepted/not-accepted and other user related data as requested by the app) to some pre-decided URL as specified at the time of registering the app.
4. That url handler (servlet/jsp) is then further responsible to get the data of the google's response request and save it in DB

Hope so that does a clear job of explaining. You can easily find more in the link as mentioned in the questions comment by LRA.